# External Content Type - Large List (5k or more)

Tags: external-content-type, external-list

I setup a external content type for a list that has ~ 6k rows (SalesPerson). I have setup the list threshold to be 50k in central admin so I can test this. I am not able to return any data when I try to create a external list based on this ECT. However, i created another ECT from a table that has few hundred rows (SalesRegions) and I am able to create External List from this ECT. I created the ECT using SharePoint Designer. Any idea what's is happening? I get "could not save changes" when I try to create an External List from SharePoint designer using SalesPerson ECT.

Answer (score 1):

when surpassing the 2,000 items you have to set up a filter in your external content type in SP designer

More info :
Define filters

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/general-development/how-to-create-external-content-types-for-sql-server-in-sharepoint.md